# System.IndexOutOfRangeException SQL Server Query in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to use selected item from my combo box for my SqlDataReader.
Which wrong in my syntax?

```
string varfunction = cbFunctionClass.SelectedItem.ToString();
con.Open();
SqlCommand sqlFunName = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + varfunction + " FROM sdn_cd_allclass WHERE MIDCLASS_CODE = '" + cbMiddleClass.Text + "'", con);
SqlDataReader sqlFunNameReader = sqlFunName.ExecuteReader();

while (sqlFunNameReader.Read())
{ lbFunctionClassName.Text = sqlFunNameReader[varfunction].ToString(); }
sqlFunNameReader.Close();
con.Close();
```

I need to use varfunction to select SQL column.

Comment: Two words: SQL Injection.

Comment: Check whether `varfunction` is column name or some number

Comment: Be sure that the name of varfunction is exactly same spelled than your header column in sql server (ie if **varfuntion = "toto"** then you should have a column named "toto"). Also you can have an sql injection. I advice you to create a stored procedure to select your data rather than a sql string (it's more safely to do that)

Comment: That exception has nothing to do with SQL. Using string concatenation exposes your code to SQL injection attacks *and* conversion errors though. What if `cbMiddeClass.Text` contained `'; drop table users;--`? Or a simple `O'Reilly'` ?

Comment: As for the error itself, you didn't explain *where* it appeared, or posted the exception itself. The full exception text, returned with `Exception.ToString()` would show the exact line that threw and contain a call stack that would show which method threw the exception. I'd bet `sqlFunNameReader[varfunction]` threw, since it's the only call that actually deals with indexes. PS if you want to retrieve a value from a reader use `DbDataReader.GetValue` or `DbDataReader.GetString()` *not* `reader[someFieldName]`

Comment: What does `varfunction` contain? Why is it called `varfunction` instead of `columnName`? To get a column value from the reader you need the column's name. If `varfunction` contains an expression, it *can't* be used to retrieve anything. You'll have to read the value by position instead of name, ie `reader.GetValue(0)` or `reader.GetString(0)`

Comment: my item list for my combo box was contained number 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, til 9. And my column name same as my item list. System.IndexOutOfRangeException was occured in "lbFunctionClassName.Text = sqlFunNameReader[varfunction].ToString();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `varfunction` contains a single digit, your query would read something like

```
SELECT 7 FROM sdn_cd_allclass...
```

for example. This would not select a column *named* `7` but the literal `7`, i.e. an integer with the value of `7`. And the column in the result, that holds this integer has no name, especially isn't its *name* `7`.

If you want to select a column *named* `7` (which probably isn't the best idea BTW) you have to quote it by putting square brackets around it, so that the query becomes

```
SELECT [7] FROM sdn_cd_allclass...
```

So try

```
 ... "SELECT [" + varfunction + "] FROM sdn_cd_allclass..." ...
```

And as an aside, like already commented many times, I also recommend you to rework this and use parameterized queries (for the literals, i.e. the value in the `WHERE` clause of your current query, it won't work with identifiers, i.e. the column name).